# Jest - mock update() function

Tags: mocking, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to mock a call to `update()` however I keep getting back the same value that I am passing in.

I guess this happens because I have no database connected and Jest is mocking the behaviour.

Using Postman, I can verify that PUT actually updates the the user in the database.

How can I mock an update function in a unit test using jest?

**user.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') user_id: string;
  @Column('text') name: string;
  @OneToMany(
    type => Post,
    post => post.user,
    {
      eager: true,
    },
  )
  posts: Post[];
  @OneToMany(
    type => Comment,
    comment => comment.user,
  )
  comments: Comment[];

  constructor(name?: string, posts?: []);
  constructor(name?: string) {
    this.name = name || '';
  }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => PostService))
    private postService: PostService,
  ) {}

  /**
   * Create a new user
   * @param data Object
   */
  async add(data: Partial<UserDTO>): Promise<User> {
    // create object with new user props
    const newUser = await this.userRepository.create(data);
    await this.userRepository.save(newUser);
    return newUser;
  }

 /**
   * Update an existing user
   * @param data Object
   */
  async edit(user_id: string, data: Partial<UserDTO>): Promise<User> {
    await this.userRepository.update({ user_id }, data);
    return this.userRepository.findOne({ user_id });
  }

  /**
   * Return one user
   */
  async findOne(user_id: string): Promise<User> {
    return await this.userRepository.findOne({
      relations: ['posts', 'comments'],
      where: { user_id },
    });
  }

... more methods

}
```

user.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import * as faker from 'faker';
import { PostService } from '../post/post.service';

// test data for user
const testUserName1 = `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.lastName()}`;

const testUserName2 = `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.lastName()}`;

// user test object
const testUser = new User(testUserName1);
const testUser2 = new User(testUserName2);

// users test array
const testUsers = [testUser, testUser2];

// mock of Post Service class
// required as these two models are related
class PostServiceMock extends PostService {}
/**
 * User Model Unit Test
 */
describe('UserService', () => {
  let userService: UserService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          // mocks of all the methods from the User Service
          useValue: {
            save: jest.fn(),
            create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(testUser),
            find: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUsers),
            findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUser),
            update: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUser),
            delete: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: PostService,
          useValue: PostServiceMock,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  });


  it('should be able to update a user', async () => {
    const newUser = await userService.add({
      name: testUserName1,
    });

    const updatedUserName = `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.firstName()}`;
    const updatedUser = await userService.edit(newUser.user_id, {
      name: updatedUserName,
    });

    expect(updatedUser).not.toBe(newUser);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you show what your `userService.add()` method does as well? Does it make use of  `userRepository.create()`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have added my `add` and `findOne` methods as well as the entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are mocking the connection to the database, you need to look at what your mock functions are returning. Following the update test that you have, let's go through this step by step:

```js
const newUser = await userService.add({name: testUser1});
```

According to your service code, `userService.add` runs `userRepostiory.create()` and `userRepository.save()`. `save` is just a stubbed method, so let's look at `create`. As we are providing a mock we'll look at what the mock returns

```js
create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(testUser)
```

So now we know that anytime we call `userRepostiory.create()` a `testUser` will be returned. Now

```js
const newUser = testUser
```

Is essentially the replacement code. Moving on we have a fake `updateUserName` that we are generating, which is pretty easy to follow. Then we run our `userService.edit()` so let's take a look at that

```js
async edit(user_id: string, data: Partial<UserDTO>): Promise<User> {
  await this.userRepository.update({ user_id }, data);
  return this.userRepository.findOne({ user_id });
}
```

So first we run `userRepository.update()` and then `userRepository.findOne()` and as we are still mocking `userRepository` lets look at those mocks. Specifically `findOne` as we don't particularly do anything with `update`'s return value.

```js
update: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testUser)
```

So `update` is also returning a `testUser`. Now if we replace our test code with the mocked substitution:

```js
const updateUser = await Promise.resolve(testUser)
```

or more simply

```js
const updateUser = testUser
```

Your assertion then is

```js
expect(udpateUser).not.toBe(newUser)
```

and with substitution we have

```js
expect(testUser).not.toBe(testUser)
```

And lo and behold, there is the issue. As both the `create()` and `findOne()` mocks are returning the same value, and same object, your user will always be the same before and after the update! To get around this, one thing you can do is mock the function to have a one time resolve value that is different like so:

```
const findSpy = jest.spyOn(userRepo, 'findOne').mockResolvedValueOnce(someUpdatedUser)
```

This will require you to get a reference to your `UserRepository` just as you are for your `UserService`, but otherwise give you the freedom to make the assertion you are expecting.